# Uncompress .Z file in unix using java

Tags: java, unix, compression

I have a .Z file present on unix box. Is there any way to call unix uncompress command from java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`java.lang.Runtime.exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Runtime.exec("uncompress " + zFilePath);
```

**UPDATE**

Accoridng to the documentation, [`ProcessBuilder.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29) is preferred.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("uncompress", zFilePath);
Process p = pb.start();
// p.waitFor();
```

Comment: how do i doi this on a windows box?

Comment: @Rookie, Same as unix assuming the `uncompress` is the directory which is list in `PATH` environmental variable.

Comment: Instead of using a system command to decompress the file I recommend to do it with a java implementation like shown in the answer of @Marian. This way you are independent of the OS your application is running on. You also avoid any security concerns related executing commands on the host system.

Comment: @MrSmith42, Nice to know that there's a library to decompress the file. I couldn't find functionality in the java standard library when I posted this answer. That's why I suggested to use `uncompress` executable.

Comment: @falsetru: I would have tried the same. Luckily Marian found that library.

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the need to decompress .Z archives, looked through internet but have found no better answer than mine below. One can use Apache Commons Compress

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("archive.tar.Z");
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("archive.tar");
ZCompressorInputStream zIn = new ZCompressorInputStream(in);
final byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
int n = 0;
while (-1 != (n = zIn.read(buffer))) {
   out.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
out.close();
zIn.close();
```

[Check this link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html)

This really works

Comment: That really helped me. Even if I decoded the file content stored in a `byte[]` instead of reading the file from a file system.